# How do you change the cancel button color in a UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller

How do we set the button's tint color in a UIImagePickerController?

I've tried setting it with the following, but this changes it for all view controllers:

```swift
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .blue
```

To change it only for UIImagePickerController I tried this, but it didn't work:

```swift
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIImagePickerController.self]).tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, declare your picker:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
```

in your pickerController construction call:

```
picker.view.tintColor = .white // Cancel button ~ any
```